# Laravel: Eloquent How to get property of model if column name contains a dash?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following in my root route:

```
$user = User::all();
return $user->column-one;
```

Which returns the exception ***Use of undefined constant one - assumed 'one'*** even though I do have a column called `column-one` from my users table. So how do I get `column-one` from my model?

Comment: Yes, you clearly can't have a variable with a dash, hence the problem. You won't always have control over the database and may have to deal with a column that has a dash in the name. Pointing the poster in the correct direction of using the Laravel getAttribute functions would be much more helpful than making a generic statement about "Learn PHP".

Comment: To downvoter, this is a real problem that many of us faced or will face. **Before downvoting please read @thaspius comment**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After digging through the source code for the eloquent model I found the magic method `__get` and learned that it was just a wrapper for the public function `getAttribute` which takes a string thus I'm now able to retrieve the column via `$user->getAttribute('column-one');`.

**Edit:**
See @Alexandre Butynski's comment below for a better solution than the one I used.

Comment: You should use getter in your model like `function getColumnOneAttribute()`, then you will be able to access your property like that : `$use->column_one`. Read the doc : http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators.

Comment: Hi @camelCaseD your solution works. @Alexandre idea doesn't work for me. I had a column like `U1-U2_max` and I created an accessor function as `public function getU1U2MinAttribute($value){ return $value; }`.  The thing is laravel wouldn't know how to put the dash between U1 and U2. If it were underscore between U1 and U2, then it would work. The purpose of an accessor is format eloquent attribute when retrieving from the model. This worked for me `{{ $post->resultats_electrique->getAttribute('U1-U2_min') }}`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but am curious if using camelCase for it would work. That's how it works for things like routes. For example: `$user->columnOne`.

I would however recommend renaming that column. That really doesn't map well in a PHP app.

Update - Try this:

$user->{"column-one"}

Comment: Sadly that returns null

Comment: Thanks but my answer below was found after a little extra digging in the source code.

Comment: @camelCaseD: Your answer might be a little slower for what it's worth. Would really recommend renaming that column... :)

Comment: Probably a good idea to try things before you post them.