# Get Hyphenated column values in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the hyphenated column values in my `laravel` application. But I'm not able to get it.

`$result->reference` this works fine.

but when I try `$result->product-id` it returns

> Undefined property: stdClass::$product

When I tried `$result->{'product-id'}`

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

How can I get this value?

Comment: use an underscore? or `object_get($result, 'product-id');`

Comment: Getting error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.   And I cannot edit the database column name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4: Eloquent How to get property of model if column name contains a dash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918278/laravel-4-eloquent-how-to-get-property-of-model-if-column-name-contains-a-dash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$result->getAttribute('product-id');
```